# VBA UserForm Edit a entry using a dynamic name range with numbers

Tags: excel, vba, edit, userform

Long time user, first post.  I have a problem with a EDIT userform in Excel.  I have a userform that allows you to enter information about projects into a database that works great.  Every entry is added to the bottom of the table.  It looks like this:

[image: Small sample of the database]

And so on.  Each project is unique, but the customer names, account manager and the project manager can repeat so I need to use the project ID for the user to select from when editing.

I want the EDIT project button to ask the user to select the project ID they want to edit.  I have a dynamic range that the combobox uses.  I am trying to validate that the combobox is working correctly.  I am following a youtube tutorial.  The tutorial basically validates by using a msg box to return the value that the user selects.  I keep getting a runtime error 1004 can't find match function when using `Application.WorksheetsFunction.Match`.  If I take out the `WorksheetsFuction` and just have `Application.Match`, I get a datatype mismatch error.  I read a comment where someone said they changed the targetrow variable to a double from integer and that worked, but it isn't working for me.  Anyone have any ideas?

Right now code is:

```
Private Sub EditProjectButton_Click()


Dim TargetRow As Integer

TargetRow = Application.Match(ProjectLineDropDown, Sheets("MetricsTracking").Range("Menu_Control"), 0)

MsgBox TargetRow
```

`ProjectLineDropDown` is the name of the combo box where the user enters which project ID they want to edit.  This combo box works as it only shows 1-however many projects there are.  This is based off a a named range, `Menu_Control`, that uses the offset command and a formula that calculates how many rows there are with data.

I want the msg box to return the same value that is entered by the user so I can confirm is working correctly.

Here is the tutorial that I followed which works good until now.  The guy in the tutorial used the name in the database as the lookup for the edit and I am using a number, I know thats where the issue is but I can't figure it out.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qKf0Gbn0N5Y

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: VBA commands and cell formula commands are not the same. You will need to include WorksheetFunction to tell VBA to treat it like a cell formula. Also, in your question you list "WorksheetsFunction" and it should be "WorksheetFunction"

Comment: Thanks, I just saw that and think I added the s by accident.  I used WorksheetFunction and got the error:  Run-time error '1004' Unable to get the match property of the WorksheetFunction class

Comment: What is `ProjectLineDropDown`? `Application.Match` will either return the index (position) of the found item,  or an error value if nothing is found. Therefore you have to declare it `As Variant` and then test the result with `IsError` or `IsNumeric` e.g. `If IsNumeric(TargetRow) Then MsgBox TargetRow Else MsgBox "No match."`

Comment: Thank you @VBasic2008!  I followed your logic to test and realized that the userform wasn't passing the drop down number as a integer because I got the "No match" error.  I changed the TargetRow variable back to Integer and added CInt to the formula and it worked! TargetRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(CInt(ProjectLineDropDown), Sheets("MetricsTracking").Range("Menu_Control"), 0)